# Creating a gradebook application

Tags: python

Can some one tell me what is wrong with my coding? I have to

1. Display all the students and their grades on the console. Your list should include a header that specifies the class name, section and grading weights.
2. Calculate the grades for all students and display this information along with the students  letter grade on the console (please note that student grades are weighted!).
3. Calculate the grade average for the class and the  letter grade for the class

Code:

```
f=open("greades.txt", "r")
sum=0
for line in f:
    #split data into rows
    items = line.split()
    sum=0
    #getting the data in rows 
    for i in range(1,9):
        sum+=int(items[i])
    print(items[0],"\tTotal:",sum,"\tAverage:",sum/9)


    def average(mygreades):
    """ Function to calculate the average of an input of the List that i have """
    if(len(mygreades)==0):
        return 0.0
    mygreades=[1]
    sum=0
    for item in mygreades:
        sum+=item

    avg = sum/len(mygreades)
    return avg

def converter(mygreades):
    """ Function will convert an input list of strings to a number list """
    numberList = []
    for item in mygreades:
        if(item.isnumeric()):
            numberList.append(eval(item))
    return numberList


main()
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Why is this tagged C?

Comment: what do you get, why is it wrong

Comment: It does not run in IDEL

Comment: Please include the error message and traceback. "Does not run" isn't helpful.

Comment: it says it is indentation error , but i dont think so

Comment: It does have an intendation error on the `def average(mygreades):` line. Or did you think the interpreter is lying to you?

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation error. Consider the following lines of code:

```
def average(mygreades):
""" Function to calculate the average of an input of the List that i have """
if(len(mygreades)==0):
```

Notice how the doc string and the `if` statement are lined up exactly under `def`. That is incorrect indentation -- the body of a function must be indented. It's also somewhat unusual to have a function defined *inside* a loop as you're doing here.

Comment: You're looking at it the wrong way round (I think). The function isn't inside the loop, the `def` has been mistakenly indented, otherwise the definition of average is return 0.0 or None.

Comment: @Ben: You're splitting hairs. You can say the def is inside the for loop and the body of the def is incorrect, or you could say the body is correct but the def is wrong. Either way, as the code exists in the question and seen by the interpreter, the def is inside the for loop. What matters is how the interpreter interprets it, and in that case, the def is in the for loop.